# In MarkerClustererPlus style parameter of MarkerClustererOptions not working properly

Tags: javascript, css, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, markerclusterer

I'm using MarkerClustererPlus and then i made an array for style parameter of MarkerClustererOptions passing different type of icons to be shown in map but it not rendering all. Its just picking up the first icon from style array not others.

```js
      function initialize() {
        var center = new google.maps.LatLng(63.078877, 21.660509);       
        var locations = [
            {name:'ABB',      lat:63.0883633,  lon:21.6609529, image:'abb.png',      webp:'http://www.abb.fi/'},
            {name:'Wartsila', lat:63.102724,   lon:21.610709,  image:'', webp:'http://www.wartsila.com/'},
            {name:'EPV',      lat:63.092265,   lon:21.55922,   image:'',      webp:'http://www.epv.fi/'},
            {name:'Vacon',    lat:63.0597281,  lon:21.7370728, image:'',    webp:'http://www.vacon.fi/'},
            {name:'Vamp',     lat:63.06153,    lon:21.735314,  image:'',     webp:'http://www.vamp.fi/'}
        ];
        var clusterStyles = [
            {textColor: 'white', url: 'do.png', height: 50, width: 50 },
            {textColor: 'white',url: 'do1.png',height: 50,width: 50},
            {textColor: 'white', url: 'do2.png', height: 50, width: 50}
        ];
          var clusterOptions = {
            styles: clusterStyles
    
                }
        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
          zoom: 3,
          center: center,
          mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        });

        var markers = [];
        for (var i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {
          var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: new google.maps.LatLng(locations[i].lat, locations[i].lon),
            icon:locations[i].image,
            url:locations[i].webp
          });
          markers.push(marker);
        }
        var markerCluster = new MarkerClusterer(map, markers,clusterOptions);
      }
      google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

```css
      body {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 10px 20px 20px;
        font-family: Arial;
        font-size: 16px;
      }
      #map-container {
        padding: 6px;
        border-width: 1px;
        border-style: solid;
        border-color: #ccc #ccc #999 #ccc;
        -webkit-box-shadow: rgba(64, 64, 64, 0.5) 0 2px 5px;
        -moz-box-shadow: rgba(64, 64, 64, 0.5) 0 2px 5px;
        box-shadow: rgba(64, 64, 64, 0.1) 0 2px 5px;
        width: 600px;
      }
      #map {
        width: 600px;
        height: 400px;
      }
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>MarkerClusterer v3 Simple Example</title>


    <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>
    <script  src="markerclusterer.js"> </script>
</head>
  <body> 
      <div id="map-container"><div id="map"></div></div>
  </body>
  </html>
```

Which step i'm missing and how can i fix it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To choose a specific style you have to set the `calculator` function:

> styles:   An array of ClusterIconStyle elements defining the styles of
>   the cluster markers to be used. The element to be used to style a
>   given cluster marker is determined by the function defined by the
>   calculator property.

You can se the rest of the docs [here](http://google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/markerclustererplus/docs/reference.html).

Comment: thanks i got it. I have to use setCalculator() method. Then i can set the number of marker after which style will change. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure what you expect from the styles, but I guess you misunderstood the purpose.

You have defined 3 styles, what means:

- the 1st style will be used for clusters with less than 10 markers
- the 2nd style will be used for clusters with 10-99 markers
- the 3rd style will be used for all other clusters

In your code you   create 5 markers(which will be clustered), so the Markerclusterer will always use the first style, because there are always less than 10 markers.

Add more markers to the Markerclusterer, and when a cluster contains more than 9 (or more than 99) markers the other icons will be used too.